# Query of custom post types only shows first post

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I have a loop to show my custom post type of 'case_studies'. It originally showed all posts until I wanted to just show 3 specific posts. The problem is that it only shows the first post in my list of 'p=54,49,44'. What am I doing wrong?

```
$case_studies = new WP_Query();
                $count = 0; 
                $case_studies->query('post_type=case_studies&p=54,49,44');  
                while($case_studies->have_posts()) : $case_studies->the_post(); $count++;
                    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                    $case_studies_image_url = $custom['second_image'][0];
```

Comment: `p` parameter is for single post selection(just a specific one), if you need a group use `post__in` as suggested by Steve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change:

```
$case_studies->query('post_type=case_studies&p=54,49,44');
```

to

```
$case_studies->query_posts( array( 'post__in' => array( 54, 49, 44 ) ) );
```

I'd look at this page for LOTS more examples. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts. when your there search for "Multiple Posts/Pages Handling".

Hope this helps, I'm still new to wordpress.

Comment: You should really use `get_posts()` instead of `query_posts()`.

_"The query_posts() function is intended to be used to modify the main page loop only. It is not intended as a means to create secondary loops on the page. If you want to create separate Loops outside of the main one, you should use get_posts() instead. Use of query_posts() on loops other than the main one can result in your main loop becoming incorrect and possibly displaying things that you were not expecting."_

(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Important_Notes)

Comment: There is no `WP_Query->query_posts()` **method**, you are confusing it with `query_posts()` **function**. `$case_studies->query()` is correct.

Comment: @Steve Fischer - Nice answer.

Comment: @Rarst & @MikeSchinkel I appologize. I mis-typed. I think I meant $case_studies = query_posts(.....

Comment: @Steve Fischer your advice on `post__in` is accurate, but `query_posts()` is unfitting for secondary loop - `WP_Query` object as in question or `get_posts()` as per @tnorthcutt comment are appropriate.

Comment: I've tried all of these suggestion and it still only shows the first of the three posts I'm trying to include. Here is my current code:     <?php 
     $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'case_studies',
      'post__in' => array('54,49,44')
     );
     query_posts($args);
     $count = 0; 
     while(have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++;
      $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
      $case_studies_image_url = $custom['second_image'][0];
    ?>

Comment: I don't think this is the reason but, you need "endwhile;" before the closing php tag.